# RAID performance with 10xSSD on an HP P420i

Tags: raid, hp, ssd, hp-smart-array

I am planning to use 10x `8TB Samsung 870 QVO SATA III 2.5" SSD` in an `HP DL360 G8` server that uses `P420i smart array` controller.

Each SSD has a max of 530 MBs speed in sequential reads. Theoretically, a `RAID-5` configuration gives 5300 MBs (10x530 MBs) read speed.

SSD's connection port is SATA. P420i has 6Gbps speed, so it is more than the SSD speed.

Is there any bottleneck in this configuration that may prevent reaching the theoretical read speed?

Answer (score 1):

**The QVO SSDs are absolutely improper for hardware RAID-5 or RAID-6 arrays.**

Don't even try, I did, and it doesn't work at all. The reason is the way these drives work: they can't sustain the long writes necessary to initialize the array -- they're using a 4 GB SLC cache for performance, any write bigger than 4GB will be so slow that the RAID controller will think the SSD doesn't respond and fail it. So you'll set up your array, and after initializing the first 40GB of the array the initialisation/rebuild will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want higher performance and throughput, make sure to use RAID10.By this will get doubled performance.

Also having Min.1GB of Cache is a good option on your controller.